# ImportError: No module named asgi

Tags: django, python-3.x, channel

Why does :

```
from channels.asgi import get_channel_layer
```

results in :

```
from channels.asgi import get_channel_layer
ImportError: No module named asgi
```

I am using Django (1.9) and python(3.4). And, while editing in pycharm, i see the IDE is giving me the quick tip for me.

Comment: have you installed `channels`?  to install, use  `pip install -U channels`

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this; if you are using channels 2, the channel layer is quite different from the older version.

I suggest you to try the following:

1. Confirm that you have configured your channel layer on `settings.py`:

   ```
   CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
       "default": {
           "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
           "CONFIG": {
               "hosts": [("redis-server-name", 6379)],
           },
       },
   }
   ```

   Hopefully, you have installed redis if using redis.
2. Add the channel layer to `asgi.py` file:

   ```
   from channels.layers import get_channel_layer

   channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
   ```

You can see [this](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html) solution.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've installed it and double check you've activated the virtualenv.

```
pip install -U asgi_redis
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
pip show channels
```

To see the version of your package.

channels.asgi was not there until version 0.9:

https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels/tree/0.8/channels
https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels/tree/0.9/channels

Comment: I already have channels in my site packages.. Below is my showchannel version..
---
Name: channels
Version: 0.10.2
Location: /home/siva/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Requires: Django, asgiref, daphne

Comment: Are you using virtualenv to manage your python packages? If not, I'm guessing that might have something to do with two versions of Python, since 2.7 should be installed by default.

Comment: Yes...  I am using virtualenv.. Is that anything to do with my set up.. I am completly new to python/Linux and this eco-system. :(

Comment: There are a few things you could try: 1. use "pip freeze --local" inside and outside the virtualenv, to see the actual packages you installed, along with the version numbers. Check if they look good. 2. actually before you do #1, check if you enabled virtualenv when running Django.  This looks very much like a package version VS python version conflicts to me.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely the asgi.py file you created is in the wrong directory.

It should be in the same directory as your settings.py and wsgi.py files.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when I was debugging a server and running the daphne command from the command line. I was running a command like:

```
/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myapp/bin/python /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myapp/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8080  core.asgi:channel_layer
```

And it was still failing. Turns out I had to `cd` into the same directory as `manage.py` to get it running. If you're using something like `systemctl`, you can just set the working directory to the same location.