# ("Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module %r" % path) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module 'asgi'

Tags: python, django

My settings.py file:

```
    """
Django settings for myproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.13.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'af^zgg5*t&h)3dghcvd#9o1@st9b(bgh@5a32%m%!g38u(tl!f'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'chat',
    'channels',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'asgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

And my asgi.py:

```
"""
ASGI config for myproject project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/asgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application()
})
```

Error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 02, 2022 - 07:12:02
Django version 3.0, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 3.0.4 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 28, in get_default_application
    module = importlib.import_module(path)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asgi'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner

    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\channels\management\commands\runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    application=self.get_application(options),
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\channels\manag
unserver.py", line 132, in get_application
    return StaticFilesWrapper(get_default_application())
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\channels\routi
 in get_default_application
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module %r" % path)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module 'asgi'
```

i have updated my django from 2.2 to 3.0 but the problem don't go please do something
and the asgi.py file was created by me
just want the server to recognize the routing application and start working
I've followed the channels 2 tutorial, but I'm getting this error after runningI've followed the channels 2 tutorial, but I'm getting this error after runningI've followed the channels 2 tutorial, but I'm getting this error after running

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named asgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270729/importerror-no-module-named-asgi)

Answer (score 0):

```
# WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'asgi.application'
```

Note how the WSGI example also has the project name?  I suspect you need to include projectname in the setting, eg,

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'projectname.asgi.application'
```

The channels docs seems to support this format (https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html)